# Multiple condition matched data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with 70 rows. The column 1 divided in 7 parts with 10 rows each. The lines are merged from 1 to 10 , 11 to 20.. and so on. and named as R1, R2.. to R7.
The column 2 has 10 unique names for first 10 rows means for R1, let's says R11 to R20, and same names are copied for next 10 rows R21 to R30 means for R2.
The actual data is in 3rd column for each rows and it's a some number/text.

I am creating a master sheet for summary. so I would like to match let's say R3 and for that R3 there are 10 rows R31- R40, so one of them let's R35. If both R3 and R35 match, I would like to get the value from 3rd column and print in the cell.

Any suggestion that How can I do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us the data, and what you've already tried. Please don't expect us to solve your problem from scratch.

Comment: When you say "I would like to match let's say R3", what exactly do you mean? Do you have a single value which you need to match R3 and R35 (say), or do you have two inputs, with the first to be matched on column 1 and the second on column 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These formulas will work if your list data is in columns A, B, C. The value you want to match from column A (example "R3") should be in G1. The value you want to match from column B (example "R35") should be in G2

Option 1: `FILTER` and `CHOOSECOLS`

`FILTER` will filter your list based on the values you want to match, for example R3 and R35.

`CHOOSECOLS` will let you just return column 3.

```
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A:C,(A:A=G1)*(B:B=G2)),3)
```

Option 2: `SUMIFS` will technically add up all the values from column 3, where there is a match in column 1 and column 2. As long as your values in column 2 are unique, this should word for you.

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,G1,B:B,G2)
```

[image]

Comment: There is only problem with this. It does not work if I merge A1 and A2 in write R1. In that case , it considers only the first R11, but does not try to match for R12. Is there any solution for that please suggest